# Rich media share - Unable to parse form content Linkedin API v2

Tags: post, linkedin-api, media, rich-media

While sharing a stored image works great (tried with postman). I could not make it work with an `url` of an image (SS3).

I have tried to send the `URL as an URL, blob, buffer, base64` but each time I get this message in return `400: Unable to parse form content`

Example of how I am trying to share as a blob.

`const mediaUrl = https://d29fp8qybdwwik.cloudfront.net/bBKZjMgj6TZZwSJot/uE7Fjrk6BA-brooke-lark-500193-unsplash.jpg`

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
};



const blob = await axios
    .get(mediaUrl, {
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then(response =>
        response.data
    );

const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload';
const data = new FormData();
data.append('fileupload', blob);
const response = await axios.post(url, data, config);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: 
Linkedin's v2 API is a nightmare

Comment: Could not agree more "Linkedin's v2 API is a nightmare"

Comment: Agree! Did you find a solution for this?? @Nicholas

Comment: @eugenioValeiras, yes. but through another path.

upload image as richMedia, then they will give you a url, after that upload at `ugcPosts` to the linked in.

Comment: Can you please share the solution in this post? So I can check it and resolve my issue!? :)

Comment: @Nicholas Can you please share with me the soliucion??